# как узнать хэш-алгоритм по сертификату

Tags: хеширование, сертификат

в структуре CERT_INFO есть элемент SignatureAlgorithm

```
typedef struct _CERT_INFO {
DWORD                       dwVersion;
CRYPT_INTEGER_BLOB          SerialNumber;
CRYPT_ALGORITHM_IDENTIFIER  SignatureAlgorithm;
CERT_NAME_BLOB              Issuer;
FILETIME                    NotBefore;
FILETIME                    NotAfter;
CERT_NAME_BLOB              Subject;
CERT_PUBLIC_KEY_INFO        SubjectPublicKeyInfo;
CRYPT_BIT_BLOB              IssuerUniqueId;
CRYPT_BIT_BLOB              SubjectUniqueId;
DWORD                       cExtension;
PCERT_EXTENSION             rgExtension;
} CERT_INFO, *PCERT_INFO;
```

как я думаю это алгоритм шифрования хэша. А вот как узнать алгоритм вычисления хэша по сертификату?

Answer (score 0):

Это прописывается в той самой структуре CRYPT_ALGORITHM_IDENTIFIER. Вот, например, одно из возможных значений ее поля (из MSDN):

> "szOID_RSA_MD5 - RSA algorithm coupled with an MD5 message digest
>   algorithm that hashes the message contents before signing."

Comment: а как узнать то именно алгоритм хэширования? У меня pRecipientCert->pCertInfo->SignatureAlgorithm.pszObjId = 1.2.643.2.2.3, хотя знаю точно что алгортим хэширования должен быть равен 1.2.643.2.2.9.Т.к. тока с этим значением и подписывает.

Comment: Неужели надо перебирать все возможные значения в завистимости от coupled value?